# Formik Antd isSubmitting not updating

Tags: antd, formik

When using Formik-antd, the isSubmitting property does not change to true when the form is being submitted.

According to Formik's [documentation](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/form-submission):

> **Pre-submit**
>
> - isSubmitting [is set] to true
>
> **Submission**
>
> - Proceed with running your submission handler (i.e.onSubmit or
>     handleSubmit)
> - *you* call setSubmitting(false) in your handler to finish
>     the cycle

Here is a sandbox demonstrating this issue. I would expect that isSubmitting would change to true on button click and stay that way.

https://codesandbox.io/s/formikantd-cvtjr

Whats interesting is that if there is an error/exception in the onSubmit callback, the isSubmitting does change to true.